# How to attach shower taps to vertically arranged water pipes?

Tags: shower, old-pipes

I have an old Jacuzzi brand shower shower cabin that needs to go, and be replaced with a shower basin + sliding doors.

The problem is that the two wall water outlet pipes (hot/cold) are vertically aligned and about eye high. That's no problem for the old cabin where they simply used flexible hoses. Typically you have the two pipes horizontally aligned and can fix the dual tap straight onto it.

The two pipes are pretty near the corner. So my idea is to fix a large plate as cover, and strong enough to hold the taps and then have hoses hide behind that cover.

I wonder if there are other options for situations where the water pipes come out sort of randomly from the wall.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a CAD drawing, how about a picture of the actual installation? That might help.

Comment: If you want in-wall plumbing you'll have to break the wall open.  If you want to leave the wall and use the existing supply lines, I think the easiest way is with a shower panel that connects to them with hoses.  You might have to hack the panel a little so the hoses can protrude from the housing and connect to the lines where they are.  Let us know more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes it's just a simple CAD sketch because the plastic cabin shower is still there and hard to move. Sorry for that.

Comment: A picture of the shower stall in place with a closeup of the plumbing can still be helpful. Sometimes a details that's critical to someone else may not be obvious for you to include, so you leave it out of your drawing...

Comment: Update: I will use a shower panel - it's like a box and I can uses hoses to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern showers have mixer valves which are installed in the wall and only the shower head pipe or tub spout come out of the wall.  The hot and cold pipes are feed to the mixer.

In the case of mixer valves that are not embedded in the wall ( something like a hansgrohe ), the hot and cold stubs come out at a precise separation.  The rough in kit includes a bar that locks into the hot and cold stub to ensure once the finish material is on the wall the external mixing valve can be aligned and look level/plumb/square with the finished material.

You could probably rig something up and keep the pipes where they are but it would likely be more work than just moving them to the spot where your new mixing valve is going to be installed.

Moving water supplies lines isn't a huge task in the scheme of a bathroom reno.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will go for a shower panel (similar Roca essential 2.0) and feed in the hoses from the side. Seems fairly easy.